# Design for game achievement system with multiple levels

Tags: mysql, database-design

I design a game achievement system for a MySQL database. Each achievement has 3 levels and each level contains a different reward. Achievements and their levels and rewards are the same for every user.

Table `achievement`:

| id_achievement | title | description | level_1 | level_2 | level_3 | reward_1 | reward_2 | reward_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

The description column will be `VARCHAR` and contain a description of how to achieve the achievement with a placeholder for the level value. Each level will be an `INT` (value needed to complete that level).

Table `user_achievement`:

| id_user | id_achievement | progress | reward_collected | achievement_completed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

My idea is to calculate the level for an achievement by comparing progress to achievement's level.

Please point out weaknesses and recommend improvements (efficiency, storage, etc.). One issue is if user does not collect their reward for completing an achievement's level before completing the next, previous reward will be overridden/skipped.

Comment: Yeah, it's a poor design.  Level_x and reward_x are repeating groups and should not be part of the achievement table.  I also don't really understand what you are going for.  Why would you get the same achievement 3 times, with the only difference being the level/reward.  If you absolutely have to do this, then there should be a one-to-many relationship between achievement and a table like achievement_level, with the level and reward in the child table.

Comment: @gview Thanks for your reply.  The achievement design i'm going for is similar to that of Clash of Clans.  An example would be destroy 5 bushes for level 1, destroy 50 for level 2 and so on... What do you think of the user_achievement table,  does it seem sufficient or are there some flaws?

Comment: user_achievement is ok, although again, if you have normalized level out as I suggested, you will have either a mult-segment key for achievement_level or it's own key, and at that point, the user_achievement needs the foreign key to be that table, and not the base achievement table as you have it now.

Comment: I personally don't like the idea of redundantly storing something that can easily be calculated, and will need to be constantly updated, so I don't know that I would store a row for a user until they had gotten to 100%, so the progress isn't something I would have or store, assuming that you already have the points or whatever other statistic is involved, stored with the user as they play.  If you do do it this way, you will need to add rows for every achievement when a new user is created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initial design is a good start. However, you need to focus on some areas to improve your design efficiency and also to address the issue you mentioned. Some suggestions are mentioned below,

1. Seperate achievements and levels:

Achievement:
id_achievement (PK), title, description

Level:
id_level (PK), id_achievement (FK), level_number, requirement

Reward:
id_reward (PK), id_achievement (FK), level_number, reward_details

2. Create a table to store the progress of the user at the level level rather than achievement level.

user_achievement_progress:
id_user (FK), id_level (FK), progress

3. Create a table to track the record collection also to prevent overriding or skipping of records.

user_reward_collection:
id_user (FK), id_reward (FK)

And also its mentioned that VARCHAR is being used, so make sure to have an appropriate length for column so that storage can be optimized.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a normalized table that will need more tables, but keep the tabels clear of repattitions

**Achievement**

| id_achievement | title | description |
| --- | --- | --- |

**level**

| id_achievement | level | numberofitem | reward |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

**user_achievement**

| id_user | id_achievement | progress | status | level |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

**status**

| id_status | statusreached |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | reward_collected |
| 2 | achievement_completed |